# XHR Upload Progress, HTTP/2 and antivirus

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, xmlhttprequest

I have switch to http/2 and apache but upload progress does not work anymore.

I have track event.loaded in console and It reaches too fast 100% when the real upload is not finished, sometimes it's just started.

When i switch back to HTTP/1.1 all working fine with same function.

I have search all day about that problem and found some interesting post where other users report that anivirus was problem. On my pc i have Eset Internet Security and when i disable HTTPS scaning xhr progress is working normal. But also when i enable antivirus but disable http2 on site upload progress working fine. So only with http2 and antivirus enabled i have this problems.
There is any solution for this?
This is example and part of code which should back progress of upload.

```
 function uploadFile_() { 
        var filedata = new FormData();
        filedata.append("file1",file);
    
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, function(e) {      
            if (prevLoaded !== 0 && e.loaded <= prevLoaded) {
                xhr.abort();
                return;
            }
            prevLoaded = e.loaded;
        },false);   
        xhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false); 
        xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        xhr.open("POST", 'https://example.com/upload-api/video',true);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.send(filedata);
    }
    
    function progressHandler(event) { 
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;
        console.log(percent);
    }
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Progress event not firing as often in http2 and everything finishes so quickly. but nothing is done. when i switch to http 1.1 everything working fine. it think this has something to do with http2 header compression or multiplexing. Did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did

added a new loaction to handle upload

```
location = /upload {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:80/upload.bin;
   }
```

now with http2 post request the file is getting uploaded also working on http1.1

Answer by for my question by @Ferrybig

This is intentional.

NGINX knows that your renderer for a 405 error doesn't need any body, so with HTTP, it discards any received data. This is really how HTTP1.1 has been designed.

With HTTP2, it becomes smarter, it tells the other side to abort sending data, and sends the resulting page. This is done to prevent wasting internet packets for data that is going to be discarded anyway.

The way HTTP2 and higher works, is just smarter and wastes less of your data for things that are already known (for example, if you need to login for a file upload, it just tells the client as soon as possible that there is an error, instead waiting until your full file has been uploaded)

When you send a request to a .php file, the php process takes it over, and it doesn't have a way to instantly return a result, so NGINX streams the whole page to php before showing the error, because PHP only starts executing the code on the page once the file has been received, and it might do something with the POST request